# how to resume an elixir task from where it broke Elixir Phoenix

Tags: rest, elixir

We are using [SeaweedFS](https://github.com/chrislusf/seaweedfs) which is a file system to store (image) files, It works as a `rest` api. We are trying to move data from one server to another.

there are a few levels of data directories. The basic pattern through which an image is stored is

```
http://{server}:8888/ballymore-project-wave/snapshots/recordings/{year}/{month}/{day}/{hour}/00_00_000.jpg
```

Each level of the directory has its own return, in form of `JSON` such as

```
{
    "Path": "/ballymore-project-wave/snapshots/recordings/",
    "Files": null,
    "Directories": [
        {
            "Name": "2016",
            "Id": 91874
        },
        {
            "Name": "2017",
            "Id": 1538395
        }
    ],
    "Limit": 100,
    "LastFileName": "",
    "ShouldDisplayLoadMore": false
}
```

above response is for when you trying to get years for recordings, same responses are for the month, days and an hour. there is a slight change when you fetch single hour as

```
{
    "Path": "/ballymore-project-wave/snapshots/recordings/2016/11/02/01/",
    "Files": [
        {
            "name": "00_00_000.jpg",
            "fid": "29515,744a5a496b97ff98"
        },
        {
            "name": "00_01_000.jpg",
            "fid": "29514,744a5aa52ea3cf3d"
        }
    ],
    "Directories": null,
    "Limit": 100,
    "LastFileName": "02_15_000.jpg",
    "ShouldDisplayLoadMore": true
}
```

Now we need to move all this data from one server to another. I wrote a script for it as

```
  defp move_snapshots(exids) do
    exids
    |> Enum.each(fn (exid) ->
      request_from_seaweedfs("#{@seaweedfs}/#{exid}/snapshots/recordings/", "Directories", "Name")
      |> Enum.sort |> Enum.each(fn (year) ->
        request_from_seaweedfs("#{@seaweedfs}/#{exid}/snapshots/recordings/#{year}/", "Directories", "Name")
        |> Enum.sort |> Enum.each(fn (month) ->
          request_from_seaweedfs("#{@seaweedfs}/#{exid}/snapshots/recordings/#{year}/#{month}/", "Directories", "Name")
          |> Enum.sort |> Enum.each(fn (day) ->
            request_from_seaweedfs("#{@seaweedfs}/#{exid}/snapshots/recordings/#{year}/#{month}/#{day}/", "Directories", "Name")
            |> Enum.sort |> Enum.each(fn (hour) ->
              request_from_seaweedfs("#{@seaweedfs}/#{exid}/snapshots/recordings/#{year}/#{month}/#{day}/#{hour}/?limit=3600", "Files", "name")
              |> Enum.sort |> Enum.each(fn (file) ->
                exist_on_seaweed?("/#{exid}/snapshots/recordings/#{year}/#{month}/#{day}/#{hour}/#{file}")
                |> copy_or_skip("/#{exid}/snapshots/recordings/#{year}/#{month}/#{day}/#{hour}/#{file}")
              end)
            end)
          end)
        end)
      end)
    end)
  end
```

This is the main function, `exids` meant to be all cameras string type identification, for above example, it is `ballymore-project-wave`.

In the above script, I am checking each level and if something is present I am going deeper and till last, I check whether its a valid image as

```
  defp exist_on_seaweed?(url) do
    hackney = [pool: :seaweedfs_download_pool, recv_timeout: 30_000_000]
    case HTTPoison.get("#{@seaweedfs}#{url}", ["Accept": "application/json"], hackney: hackney) do
      {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 200, body: data}} -> {:ok, data}
      _error ->
        :not_found
    end
  end

  defp copy_or_skip(:not_found, _path), do: :noop
  defp copy_or_skip({:ok, data}, path) do
    hackney = [pool: :seaweedfs_upload_pool]
    case HTTPoison.post("#{@seaweedfs_new}#{path}", {:multipart, [{path, data, []}]}, [], hackney: hackney) do
      {:ok, _response} -> Logger.info "[seaweedfs_save]"
      {:error, error} -> Logger.info "[seaweedfs_save] [#{inspect error}]"
    end
  end
```

This is all working fine But I have a slight issue of resuming this when it get crashed or broke due to some reason, I need guidance/idea for this. As you can see if camera `exids` are 200 and it get broke on 100 or maybe less, it will resume but from the very start, we cannot delete things on old server after moving until the full movement, Any help will be appreciated. Also if you think there could be some improvements in the code that would be helpful.

Comment: Can you do it recursively? Tree traversal usually is a recursion and resuming should be much easier.

Or a much easier way: traverse the file list first, save it somewhere, and process the file list concurrently.

Comment: @chrislusf Hello Chris thanks for the reply, what I thought was to move the file to a new path as I moved on next one as if camera_eixd will become _camera_exid it will not be checked next. File list? hmm but files are for 2 years almost they are going to be in million or billions.

Answer (score 1):

Until you post the actual stacktrace or details of the error you are encountering, it's not possible to figure out exactly what's wrong. But for starters, here are some suggestions that might help:

- You should break down your `move_snapshots` method into something more understandable, maybe using something like [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3) with recursion and calling your `copy_or_skip` method as the base case.
- Try wrapping your `copy_or_skip` method implementation inside a [`try/rescue`](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/try-catch-and-rescue.html), rescuing any exceptions, logging them and moving on to the next one.

  ```
  defp copy_or_skip(args, path) do
    # Your Implementation
  rescue
    error -> Logger.error("Exception caught on #{inspect(path)}\n#{inspect(error)}")
  end
  ```
- You could also just go through the list of all files, and add the valid paths to some "Worker" in a Job processing library like [`Que`](https://github.com/sheharyarn/que) or [`Toniq`](https://github.com/joakimk/toniq). The library will perform all the move operations and mark them successful or failed. You could then go back to see which operations failed and figure out what caused them, or automatically restart the failed ones.

---

Some more tips on improving code reliability and performance:

- Use [`Stream`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Stream.html), or better yet, [`Flow`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/flow/) to divide the tasks and process them in parallel.
- Perform the actual move operation in a separate [`Task`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html) process, ideally managed by [`Supervisor`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html). (Optionally use a Pool).

Comment: Thank you. But the question is how to resume it when it gets broke. for example. I ran the task in the remote console of application and it running but we need to deploy the application again not hot code. but scratch deploy now there was no error but deploy will suspend all running process after a restart. then

Comment: Yes, then you should use a Job processing library or manually supervise tasks in your OTP application, and restart failed processes. See answer again.

Comment: @Sheharyar it seems the `try` is missing in your `try/rescue` code. Or maybe you can use it without try, things that I am not aware of...

Comment: @NathanRipert you don't need to write `try` when you want to rescue the entire function.

Comment: @Sheharyar I really appreciate your answer but I am already stating that I was looking for some other solution.  Not using another `dep` and also what if Application stopped and restarted again. will Flow, Supervisor? Que, Toniq will know what happened? Nope :) I hope you understand. I was looking for some kind of solution where I can save the file with last url on which task was going etc

Comment: Actually, background job services will know (if each file is handled in a separate job). So even after the app crashes and is restarted, they can continue from where they left off.