# Resume Enum.each operation when reading data from a file in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I have this kind of `Enum.each` going through many eachs.

```
exids
|> Enum.each(fn (exid) ->
  request_from_seaweedfs("#{@seaweedfs}/#{exid}/snapshots/recordings/", "Directories", "Name")
  |> Enum.sort |> Enum.each(fn (year) ->
    request_from_seaweedfs("#{@seaweedfs}/#{exid}/snapshots/recordings/#{year}/", "Directories", "Name")
    |> Enum.sort |> Enum.each(fn (month) ->
      request_from_seaweedfs("#{@seaweedfs}/#{exid}/snapshots/recordings/#{year}/#{month}/", "Directories", "Name")
      |> Enum.sort |> Enum.each(fn (day) ->
        request_from_seaweedfs("#{@seaweedfs}/#{exid}/snapshots/recordings/#{year}/#{month}/#{day}/", "Directories", "Name")
        |> Enum.sort |> Enum.each(fn (hour) ->
          request_from_seaweedfs("#{@seaweedfs}/#{exid}/snapshots/recordings/#{year}/#{month}/#{day}/#{hour}/?limit=3600", "Files", "name")
          |> Enum.sort |> Enum.each(fn (file) ->
            exist_on_seaweed?("/#{exid}/snapshots/recordings/#{year}/#{month}/#{day}/#{hour}/#{file}")
            |> copy_or_skip("/#{exid}/snapshots/recordings/#{year}/#{month}/#{day}/#{hour}/#{file}")
            save_current_directory(exid, year, month, day, hour, file)
          end)
        end)
      end)
    end)
  end)
  next_exid_index = Enum.find_index(exids, fn(x) -> x == exid end)
  File.write!("#{@root_dir}/moving_old_data", "#{Enum.at(exids, next_exid_index + 1)}")
end)
```

This is a very long time running loop, but it's not handling any stop and resume logic.

I tried to save current data to a file and resume it from there on restart as

```
exids
|> clean_already_completed(0)
|> Enum.each(fn (exid) ->
  request_from_seaweedfs("#{@seaweedfs}/#{exid}/snapshots/recordings/", "Directories", "Name")
  |> Enum.sort |> clean_already_completed(1) |> Enum.each(fn (year) ->
    request_from_seaweedfs("#{@seaweedfs}/#{exid}/snapshots/recordings/#{year}/", "Directories", "Name")
    |> Enum.sort |> clean_already_completed(2) |> Enum.each(fn (month) ->
      request_from_seaweedfs("#{@seaweedfs}/#{exid}/snapshots/recordings/#{year}/#{month}/", "Directories", "Name")
      |> Enum.sort |> clean_already_completed(3) |> Enum.each(fn (day) ->
        request_from_seaweedfs("#{@seaweedfs}/#{exid}/snapshots/recordings/#{year}/#{month}/#{day}/", "Directories", "Name")
        |> Enum.sort |> clean_already_completed(4) |> Enum.each(fn (hour) ->
          request_from_seaweedfs("#{@seaweedfs}/#{exid}/snapshots/recordings/#{year}/#{month}/#{day}/#{hour}/?limit=3600", "Files", "name")
          |> Enum.sort |> clean_already_completed(5) |> Enum.each(fn (file) ->
            exist_on_seaweed?("/#{exid}/snapshots/recordings/#{year}/#{month}/#{day}/#{hour}/#{file}")
            |> copy_or_skip("/#{exid}/snapshots/recordings/#{year}/#{month}/#{day}/#{hour}/#{file}")
            save_current_directory(exid, year, month, day, hour, file)
          end)
        end)
      end)
    end)
  end)
  next_exid_index = Enum.find_index(exids, fn(x) -> x == exid end)
  File.write!("#{@root_dir}/moving_old_data", "#{Enum.at(exids, next_exid_index + 1)}")
end)
```

whereas `clean_already_completed` works like that.

```
  defp clean_already_completed(list, index), do: get_recent_value(index) |> dont_reduce?(list)

  defp dont_reduce?(nil, list), do: list
  defp dont_reduce?(last, list), do: Enum.drop_while(list, fn el -> el != last end)

  defp get_recent_value(index), do: read_recent_file() |> Enum.at(index)

  defp read_recent_file, do: File.read("#{@root_dir}/moving_old_data") |> file_is_present()

  defp file_is_present({:error, :enoent}), do: []
  defp file_is_present({:ok, ""}), do: []
  defp file_is_present({:ok, data}), do: data |> String.split(" ")
```

But it's not working as expected when I stop and restart it, even while running. It skips the next coming year, days and months.

In the saved file, I have this kind of data

```
1-granby-row 2017 03 18 05 43_49_000.jpg
```

For example on failure, I just want to resume each loops from these values. the above line is explained as `exid year month day hour file`.

Is there any possible way to do it in a better way? that from file information in case the whole loop starts again, resume it from there?

Answer (score 0):

**A better way would be to divide the process into smaller steps:**

1. Run the nested `each` statements to build a manifest of all files that need to be moved.
2. Store the full paths to these files to a persistent data store like Redis, Postgres or Mnesia.
3. Now iterate through all these paths, moving the files and marking them "done" when they have been transferred succesfully.
4. For whatever reason, when the application crashes or the process is stopped in the middle, you could restart the application and continue from where you left off. Since you already have a resolved list of all files, their paths and statuses, you can just select the next path that is marked "not done", and continue moving it.

---

Like I have already mentioned [in my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52510788/1533054) previously, this can all be done simply using a job processing library; all you need to do is resolve all paths and add them as jobs that need to be processed. In case of errors, crashes and other failures, they can restart the "jobs" that have been failed and resume the jobs that haven't been completed.

---

Here's what the code would look like if you decide to do it without a job processing library:

```
# Steps 1 and 2
def build_manifest do
  all_files =
    exids
    |> Enum.map(fn exid -> "#{@seaweedfs}/#{exid}/snapshots/recordings/" end)
    |> Enum.flat_map(&get_dir_paths/1)         # Get Year directories
    |> Enum.flat_map(&get_dir_paths/1)         # Get Month directories
    |> Enum.flat_map(&get_dir_paths/1)         # Get Day directories
    |> Enum.flat_map(&get_dir_paths/1)         # Get Hour directories
    |> Enum.flat_map(&get_file_paths/1)        # Get files in the hour directories

  # Now store these files to a datastore
end


# Steps 3 & 4
def copy_all_files do
  case get_next_incomplete_file() do
    nil ->
      IO.puts("All files have been copied")

    path ->
      if exist_on_seaweed?(path)
        copy_file(path)
      end

      copy_all_files()
  end
end


defp get_dir_paths(path) do
  path
  |> request_from_seaweedfs("Directories", "Name")
  |> Enum.sort
  |> Enum.map(&Path.join(path, &1))
end

defp get_file_paths(path) do
  (path <> "?limit=3600")
  |> request_from_seaweedfs("Files", "Name")
  |> Enum.sort
  |> Enum.map(&Path.join(path, &1))
end

defp get_next_incomplete_file do
  # query your datastore to get the next file that is
  # marked "not done"
end

defp copy_file(path) do
  # copy the file
  # and then mark it "done" in the datastore
end
```

Comment: There is 70TB * 4 server which includes trillions of files, You are suggesting again to save the manifest? send trillions of request to save the paths first and then again requests to copy files :)

Comment: I understand your all solutions but you ae not understand the problem. its a filesystem, Server is running on one server and Seaweedfs is running on other server as filer, and it has 4 servers attached each is 70T. There is only one way possible without creating manifest or first looping through all files. to save the last state and resume it from there. going through all files first is not a good idea at all that the reason I posted a new question with new problem

Comment: @Sheharyar now tell do you have any solution? I have told you the situation now going to through all files first would be ok?

Comment: @JunaidFarooq You are sending trillions of requests either way. Your implementation already makes these requests for both listing the files and then again for copying them. But this way you have a reliable reference of files beforehand, and don't need to get file paths again if the application crashes.